# Not able to understand pass-by-value in Java with block scope

Tags: java, string, pass-by-value

I'm learning the basics of Java and currently understanding how call-by-value works. I do know that when you pass in primitives, the copy of the value is being made hence the original value is not affected. When an object is passed, the copy of the reference variable is used, hence modifying the original object. If a String object is passed, the original value is not modified since strings are immutable:

```
static void main(String args[]) {
    String name = "Eric";
    changeName(name);
    System.out.println(name); //Eric
}

static void changeName(String nameVal) {
    nameVal = "Gabriel";
}
```

However, if an original String object does not get modified as shown above, why does it change when you use a block scope? Both the pass-by-value and block scope accept value of the reference variable and tries to change its content but one doesn't and the other does.

```
static void main(String args[]) {
    String name = "Eric";
    {
        name = "Gabriel"; 
    }
    System.out.println(name); //Gabriel
}
```

What is the key difference between both the examples above?

Comment: Variables are not _passed in_ to block scopes. The scope just has access to the outside.

Comment: Plus the value of the String is not changed. Rather, the variable name is changed to point to another String instance - one that contains Gabriel.

Comment: `nameVal = "Gabriel"` does NOT modify `newVal`, it assigns it a new value, locally. You don't modify the thing in the box, you put smoething else

Comment: If you *really* want to rewrite the method call into a block, I suppose you could rewrite it as `String name = "Eric"; { String nameVal = name; } System.out.println(name);`, which produces the same result and *sort of* maintains the same semantics with regards to what variables are passed.

Comment: Technically, I would say that Java only supports passing by values.  It pass the values of primitive variables, and values of reference variables which are memory addresses.  Java reference variables are just pointers without the C++ pointer arithmetic.  In C++, we can pass the reference of an int but we can't do that in Java.  In Java, we are just passing pointers which are values of memory addresses.